# Using Doctrine extension softdeleteable with api-platform

Tags: symfony, soft-delete, doctrine-extensions, api-platform.com

I'm building an API with Symfony 3.4 and api-platform. I want to use soft delete on my entity. I've installed `DoctrineExtensions` and `StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle`.

`config.yml`:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
               […]

    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    […]
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
```

And my entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

/**
 * MyEntity
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="MyEntity", schema="MyEntity")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\MyEntityRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ApiResource
 */
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $deletedAt;

    […]
```

This is not working. I'm aware that I need to configure something (namely the EventManager), but I don't know how.
Here is the error I get when I try to create an entity

`Listener "SoftDeleteableListener" was not added to the EventManager!`

I think I've done everything that page explains : [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/index.html)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following configuration at your `config.yml`

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    […]
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true

stof_doctrine_extensions:
    default_locale: %locale%
    orm:
        default:
            softdeleteable: true
```

**Note:** My configuration looks like:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    entity_managers:
      default:
        auto_mapping: true
        filters:
            softdeleteable:
              class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
              enabled: true
```

Seems that you're customizing your `mappings` so be sure you're autoloading the SoftDeleteable classes properly.